# Wrong text entered by sendkeys

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to automate a webpage where i have to enter credit card details.
During manually entering CVV of the credit card I am able to move forward, but while entering value using sendkeys it throws an error.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).sendKeys("999");
```

*I tried clicking on the textbox and then entered value. This also didn't work.*

*While entering value through send keys, i cant see what value is being sent because its encrypted.*

Comment: Can you try sending TAB key event after each time you enter card detail ?

Comment: IMO, `CVV` field is not TAB separated. Thanks

Comment: @Abhinav
Tried. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If on text box already text is there first clear it using following:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).sendKeys("999");
```

Or try only this

```
driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).sendKeys("999");
```

Comment: Tried both the things.The problem is that value is being entered and when i click next, i get an error that CVV is wrong/incorrect.

Comment: HTML code 
<INPUT id=password_ccCvv accessKey="" maxLength=5 size=5 name=password_ccCvv autocomplete="off" jQuery1496991594382="4">

Answer (score 0):

Try this using javascriptexecuter and let me know

In Python

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('password_ccCvv').value = '001';");
```

In Java

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('password_ccCvv').value = '001';");
```

Comment: I am using Java, so i tried the second one. I can see value being entered. but as soon as next is clicked; error message is displayed.         
Where as when i manually enter the same value, no error messages is displayed.

Comment: in my code it tries to go to the next element.
Unable to find element with id == currentAcctEmailRadio

whereas on FE

"Please enter a valid CVV"

Comment: I'm not clear which error you are facing can u be more descriptive ?

Comment: Sure. After using the code you provided above. Value is being entered in the CVV textbox.
after that I have to click on below element
driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).click();
So, when this click  is performed it is expected to go to next webpage, but it doesn;t because of the error CVV is not correct.

Comment: can you share the URL ?

Comment: After entering the value for first element does the ID changes for second element ?

Answer (score 0):

If Webdriver is not able to enter data using standard way (using **sendKeys** method), you can use a workaround using JavaScriptExecuter, as shown below:

```
JavascriptExecutor e = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
e.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")), "999");
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: I can see value being entered. but as soon as next is clicked; error message is displayed. Where as when i manually enter the same value, no error messages is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
          while(driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).isEnabled())
          {
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).sendKeys("999");
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).click();
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          }
```

This is working for me. I am able to authenticate in 3rd or 4th try.

Answer (score -1):

I erased my entered password and enter again, it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).